# Sql query to generate monthly pay dates within a date range

Tags: sql, asp.net, sql-server, date, sql-server-2012

I want to generate monthly pay dates based on a given date and date range.Suppose I have selected "01/30/2016" as a starting pay date and date range is the year 2016.Then the pay dates will be (total days of month -1) th of other months throughout the year 2016. I have added a screenshot for the result set for the pay date "01/30/2016".
I want to know the query in SQL.

Any help will be appreciated.

[image]

Comment: Kindly provide what have you tried out for this

Comment: @GopalBiswas What is sql-server version?

Comment: The version is SQL SERVER 2012.  @NEER

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can as the below:

```
DECLARE @SelectedDate DATETIME = '2016.01.30'
SELECT
     DATEADD(DAY, -1 - (DAY(EOMONTH(@SelectedDate)) - DAY(@SelectedDate)),  DATEADD(MONTH, v.m, DATEFROMPARTS(YEAR(@SelectedDate), 1, 1)))   
FROM
    (VALUES (1), (2), (3), (4), (5), (6), (7), (8), (9), (10), (11), (12)) AS v(m)
```

How many days are left before the end of the month. The number of days found is removed from other months.

`DAY(EOMONTH(@SelectedDate)`(31) - `DAY(@SelectedDate)`(30) = 
`left days`(1)

Result:

```
2016-01-30
2016-02-28
2016-03-30
2016-04-29
2016-05-30
2016-06-29
2016-07-30
2016-08-30
2016-09-29
2016-10-30
2016-11-29
2016-12-30
```

Comment: Wow... working perfectly.Just one thing to ask from you what is "v.m" in DATEADD and the last line VALUES (1), (2), (3), (4) are working in this query. @NEER

Comment: @GopalBiswas v.m is months (1, 2, 3, 4, 5, ... 12) I created months and removed left days.

Answer (score 0):

```
DECLARE @StartDate VARCHAR(10) = '01/30/2016',
        @EndDate   VARCHAR(10)='12/30/2016';

WITH _CTEDate( _date, _NextMonth)
     AS (SELECT CONVERT(DATE, @StartDate, 101),
                Eomonth(@StartDate, 1)
         UNION ALL
         SELECT Dateadd(DAY, -1, _NextMonth),
                Eomonth(Dateadd(M, 1, _date), 1)
         FROM   _CTEDate
         WHERE  _date < CONVERT(DATETIME, @EndDate, 101))
SELECT Datename(DW, _date)               [WeekDay],
       Cast(Day(_date) AS VARCHAR(2)) + ' '
       + Datename(MONTH, _date) + ' ' + ' '
       + Cast(Year(_date) AS VARCHAR(4)) AS [Date]
FROM   _CTEDate
```