# Sql query to generate monthly pay dates based on a month end date

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, date, sql-server-2012

I want to generate monthly pay dates based on a "month pay" and "month end" date for a year.Suppose I have selected "01/26/2016" as "pay date" and "01/31/2016" as "month end" date and date range is the year 2016.
Then the "month end" date will be the last day of the month for the year and pay dates will be (**"month end" date of the month - "pay date" of month**) th for other months throughout the year 2016. I have added a screenshot for the result set for the pay date "01/26/2016" and "01/31/2016" as "month end" date. My SQL version is 2012.
I want to know the query in SQL.

Any help will be appreciated.

[image]

screenshot for "02/08/2016" as "pay date" and "01/31/2016" as "month end"
[image]

Comment: Basically you need to get the **date difference** between **selected month end date** and **selected pay date** and apply the **same difference** to all other months. Is this your requirement?

Comment: Correct  @ viki888

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Same logic with your [last question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40501027/6468577).

You can as the below:

```
DECLARE @StartDate DATETIME = '2016.01.26'
DECLARE @EndDate DATETIME = '2016.01.31'

SELECT
    DATENAME(dw, A.Month) DayNameOfMonth,
    A.[Month],
    DATENAME(dw, A.[Pay Date]) DayNameOfPayDate,
    A.[Pay Date]
FROM
(
    SELECT
         DATEADD(DAY, -1 - (DAY(EOMONTH(@EndDate)) - DAY(@EndDate)),  DATEADD(MONTH, v.m, DATEFROMPARTS(YEAR(@EndDate), 1, 1))) 'Month',
         DATEADD(DAY, -1 - (DAY(EOMONTH(@StartDate)) - DAY(@StartDate)),  DATEADD(MONTH, v.m, DATEFROMPARTS(YEAR(@StartDate), 1, 1))) 'Pay Date'
    FROM
        (VALUES (1), (2), (3), (4), (5), (6), (7), (8), (9), (10), (11), (12)) AS v(m)
) A
```

Result:

```
DayNameOfMonth                 Month      DayNameOfPayDate               Pay Date
------------------------------ ---------- ------------------------------ ----------
Sunday                         2016-01-31 Tuesday                        2016-01-26
Monday                         2016-02-29 Wednesday                      2016-02-24
Thursday                       2016-03-31 Saturday                       2016-03-26
Saturday                       2016-04-30 Monday                         2016-04-25
Tuesday                        2016-05-31 Thursday                       2016-05-26
Thursday                       2016-06-30 Saturday                       2016-06-25
Sunday                         2016-07-31 Tuesday                        2016-07-26
Wednesday                      2016-08-31 Friday                         2016-08-26
Friday                         2016-09-30 Sunday                         2016-09-25
Monday                         2016-10-31 Wednesday                      2016-10-26
Wednesday                      2016-11-30 Friday                         2016-11-25
Saturday                       2016-12-31 Monday                         2016-12-26
```

**UPDATED**

```
DECLARE @StartDate DATETIME = '2016.01.31' -- month end
DECLARE @EndDate DATETIME = '2016.02.08' -- pay date

SELECT         
    DATEADD(DAY, -1 - (DAY(EOMONTH(@StartDate)) - DAY(@StartDate)),  DATEADD(MONTH, v.m, DATEFROMPARTS(YEAR(@StartDate), 1, 1))) 'Month End',        
    DATEADD(DAY, DATEDIFF(DAY, @StartDate, @EndDate), DATEADD(DAY, -1 - (DAY(EOMONTH(@StartDate)) - DAY(@StartDate)),  DATEADD(MONTH, v.m, DATEFROMPARTS(YEAR(@StartDate), 1, 1)))) 'Pay Date'
FROM
    (VALUES (1), (2), (3), (4), (5), (6), (7), (8), (9), (10), (11), (12)) AS v(m)
```

**UPDATE 2**

```
DECLARE @StartDate DATETIME = '2016.01.31' -- month end
DECLARE @EndDate DATETIME = '2016.02.08' -- pay date

SELECT
    *
FROM
(
    SELECT         
        DATEADD(DAY, -1 - (DAY(EOMONTH(@StartDate)) - DAY(@StartDate)),  DATEADD(MONTH, v.m, DATEFROMPARTS(YEAR(@StartDate), 1, 1))) 'Month End',        
        DATEADD(DAY, DATEDIFF(DAY, @StartDate, @EndDate), DATEADD(DAY, -1 - (DAY(EOMONTH(@StartDate)) - DAY(@StartDate)),  DATEADD(MONTH, v.m, DATEFROMPARTS(YEAR(@StartDate), 1, 1)))) 'Pay Date'
    FROM
        (VALUES (1), (2), (3), (4), (5), (6), (7), (8), (9), (10), (11), (12)) AS v(m)
) A
WHERE
    YEAR(A.[Pay Date]) = YEAR(@EndDate)
```

Comment: Thanks for your response but if I input '2016.01.31' as "month end" date and '2016.02.08' as "pay date" then the output is not matching with my desired result. @NEER

Comment: Only one clause needed the "PayDate" should be within the year. @NEER

Comment: Thanks again... :) @NEER

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
DECLARE @PayDate AS DATE = '2016-Jan-26', @MonthEndDate AS DATE = '2016-Jan-31'
DECLARE @Start AS INT = 0, @End AS INT = 11
DECLARE @DateDiff AS INT = (SELECT DATEDIFF(DAY, @PayDate, @MonthEndDate))

; WITH CTE AS
(
SELECT @Start as number
UNION ALL
SELECT number + 1
FROM CTE
WHERE number < @End
) SELECT 

DATENAME(dw, DATEADD(MONTH, number, @MonthEndDate)) + ', ' + convert(varchar(12), DATEADD(MONTH, number, @MonthEndDate), 113) AS MonthEnd, 
DATENAME(dw, DATEADD(DAY, -@DateDiff, DATEADD(MONTH, number, @MonthEndDate))) + ', ' + convert(varchar(12), DATEADD(DAY, -@DateDiff, DATEADD(MONTH, number, @MonthEndDate)), 113) AS PayDate 
FROM CTE

/* Output:
MonthEnd                    PayDate
---------------------------------------------------
Sunday, 31 Jan 2016         Tuesday, 26 Jan 2016
Monday, 29 Feb 2016         Wednesday, 24 Feb 2016
Thursday, 31 Mar 2016       Saturday, 26 Mar 2016
Saturday, 30 Apr 2016       Monday, 25 Apr 2016
Tuesday, 31 May 2016        Thursday, 26 May 2016
Thursday, 30 Jun 2016       Saturday, 25 Jun 2016
Sunday, 31 Jul 2016         Tuesday, 26 Jul 2016
Wednesday, 31 Aug 2016      Friday, 26 Aug 2016
Friday, 30 Sep 2016         Sunday, 25 Sep 2016
Monday, 31 Oct 2016         Wednesday, 26 Oct 2016
Wednesday, 30 Nov 2016      Friday, 25 Nov 2016
Saturday, 31 Dec 2016       Monday, 26 Dec 2016
*/
```

Comment: Only one change needed the "PayDate" should be within the year. Please see the edited question @Tanjim Rahman

Comment: What you are asking is simple logic change could be done with some condition with `@DateDiff`.

Answer (score 0):

```
DECLARE @Y int = 2016;

SELECT RD.ME MonthEnd, RD.PD PayDate FROM 
(select
 1 as mth 
union 
select 2 
union 
select 3 
union 
select 4 
union 
select 5
union 
select 6
union 
select 7 
union 
select 8
union 
select 9
union 
select 10 
union 
select 11
union 
select 12) M 
CROSS APPLY (SELECT DATEADD(month, M.mth - 1, DATEADD(year, @y - 1900, 0)) RM ) OA
CROSS APPLY (SELECT DATEADD(day, -1 , DATEADD(month, 1, OA.RM)) ME,  DATEADD(day, -6 , DATEADD(month, 1, OA.RM)) PD) RD ORDER BY RD.ME
```